# javascript arrays and looping

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

I'm jessi and I'm a web development student. I'm trying to write a program with arrays and I'm stuck.  I have an array of phrases and when a user enters a number between 1 and 10 it is supposed to show that many phrases on the screen but I'm stuck. I don't know how to display multiple results on the screen.  I'd really appreciate any help. Thanks.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <title>Get A Response</title>
  </head>

 <body>
 <form>
  <h1>Select how many phrases you want displayed.</h1>
  <input type="number" class="userInput"></input>
  <button type="submit" value="submit" onclick="showme()"></button>
 </form>

<div class="myphrases">
</div>

<script src="js/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>

  ////////////////// Javascript

 function showme() {
  var number = document.querySelector('.userInput').value;


  var display = "";

   var phrases = [
    "Hello there",
    "What's up Doc",
    "Because I said so",
    "Say it again",
    "It's a celebration",
    "Enjoy yourselves",
    "Welcome",
    "Where did you go", "Why you crying", "Stop playing"];


   var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * phrases.length);

    for(var i = 0; i < phrases.length; i++) {

    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

First, you should set up an HTML element that will serve as your output area. An empty `div` element is a good choice. You've already done that with: `<div class="myphrases"></div>`.

Next, the HTML `input` element does not get a closing tag (`</input>`) and instead of using a `submit` button, just use a regular button (since you are not actually submitting data anywhere).

Also, don't use inline HTML event handling attributes (onclick, onmouseover, etc.) as they:

1. Create spaghetti code that leads to duplication and makes the code harder to read.
2. Causes global anonymous wrapper functions to be created around your attribute's value and change the `this` binding in your callback functions.
3. Don't follow the W3C Event standard of using `.addEventListener()`.

Next, don't have your loop go over every phrase (`phrases.length`). Only have it go for the amount of times the user has entered.

Finally, you can update the `div` output area by adjusting its `innerHTML` to be a string that you build up from your loop:

```js
// Get reference to the text box, the button and the output area
var number = document.querySelector('.userInput');
var btn = document.querySelector("button");
var output = document.querySelector(".myphrases");

// Set up the event handling function for the button
btn.addEventListener("click", showme);

function showme() {
 
  var display = "";

   var phrases = [
    "Hello there",
    "What's up Doc",
    "Because I said so",
    "Say it again",
    "It's a celebration",
    "Enjoy yourselves",
    "Welcome",
    "Where did you go", "Why you crying", "Stop playing"];

   // String to hold loop results
   var result = "";
  
    // Set up the upper limit for the loop.
    // If the entered value is greater than the length of the array, use the length 
    // of the array. If not, use the value entered by the user
    var count = number.value > phrases.length ? phrases.length : number.value;
    
    for(var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * phrases.length);
      result += phrases[random] + "<br>";
    }
    
   // Inject the string into the output area
   output.innerHTML = result;
  }
```

```html
<form>
  <h1>Select how many phrases you want displayed.</h1>
  <input type="number" class="userInput">
  <button type="button">Submit</button>
 </form>

<div class="myphrases"></div>
```